# FusionCharts- changing the color of a bar on click in Column2D chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

FusionCharts- I tried creating a column2d chart. I have a requirement where in I need to click on one of the bars of the chart and refresh some data in a table below. Apart from this, I need to change the color of the bar that I have clicked. I am able to accomplish the first one using the link property to set to a javascript function and refresh the table in that function. But the second requirement (changing the color) I am not able to accomplish. I tried fetching the HTML element using the DOM and changing the color. But, I am not able to fetch the element, but the inherent object created by Raphael (fusionchart uses raphael). I also tried accessing the element using the raphaelID property of the object, but this was of no use. I want this to be done on client side, without any refresh. I also tried to use events for clicking as part of datasource for the FisionChart.

```
var barChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'column2d',
    id: chartid,
    width: w,
    height: '200',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "bgalpha": "0",
            "Bold": "0",
            "canvasbgalpha": "0",
            "canvasborderalpha": "0",
            "defaultnumberscale": "calls",
            "divlinealpha": "10",
            "formatnumberscale": "1",
            "labelDisplay": "Wrap",
            "numDivLines": "3", //changed for showing Y-axis scale
            "numVDivLines": "0", //changed for showing Y-axis scale
            "outCnvBaseFont": "Tahoma",
            "outCnvbaseFontSize": "12",
            "palettecolors": "#3399FF",
            "plotbordercolor": "#797979",
            "plotBorderHoverThickness": "1",
            "plotFillHoverColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "plotgradientcolor": "",
            "plotHoverEffect": "1",
            "plotSpacePercent": "35",
            "rotateYAxisName": "0",
            "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
            "showborder": "0",
            "showplotborder": "1",
            "showvalues": "0",
            "showYAxisValues": "1", //changed for showing Y-axis scale.
            "xaxisname": currentMonth,
            "yaxisname": "Number {br} of calls",
            "yAxisMinvalue": "0",
            "yAxisMaxValue": max //changed for showing Y-axis scale
        },
        "data": chartDataItems,
        "events": {
            "dataPlotClick": function (evtObj, argObj) {
                // Modifying the underlying Raphael object
                var i, plotItems = evtObj.sender.jsVars.hcObj.elements.plots[0].items,
                plotLength = plotItems.length;
                //                        for (i = 0; i < plotLength; i++) {
                //                            plotItems[i].graphic.attr("fill", "#FFFFFF");
                //                        }
                plotItems[argObj.dataIndex].graphic.attr("fill", "#FFFFFF");
            }
        }
    }
});
barChart.render(chartToRenderId);
```

below is my code to access the element using HTML properties.

```
 try {
        var day = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(0, 2));
        var rectangleBars = $(".red-hot-2").find("rect");
        var rectangle = rectangleBars[day - 1];
        var element = document.getElementById(rectangle.raphaelid);
        element.click(function () {
            this.attr('background-color', 'white');
        });
    }
    catch (e) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

background-color is not an attribute, try this:

```
 try {
        var day = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(0, 2));
        var rectangleBars = $(".red-hot-2").find("rect");
        var rectangle = rectangleBars[day - 1];
        var element = document.getElementById(rectangle.raphaelid);
        element.click(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        });
    }
    catch (e) { }
```